# Creating an json API with more than one database table

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

I'm creating an API with recipes. I have 3 tables: recipes, ingredients and recipe_ingredient where recipe_id and ingredients_id are foreign keys from the two other tables.

I managed to get everything from table recipe_ingredient and it works fine. My question is: **How I can get an array within this array with the information for recipes and ingredients?** I kind of understand that I have to do a kind of `join` but I don't know how I should get it in my API.

Well, it's hard to explain but I hope you understand. Here is my code:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=recipes;charset=utf8", "root", "root");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stm = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM recipe_ingredient") ;

$stm->execute();

header('Content-Type: application/json');

while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $api = json_encode($row, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    print_r($api);

}
```

Comment: The return data from these 3 tables depends on what the api will consume, or in other words what the api consumer will require to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables somehow like this

```
"SELECT * FROM recipe_ingredient left join ingredient on ingredient.id = recipe_ingredient.ingredient_id left join recipe on recipe.id = recipe_ingredient.receipe_id"
```

Then you can use a foreach loop in php to make a final result and return using api.